# How to retrieve error message with getLastAuthenticationError() on login?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-security

I have tried implementing a simple login form with both Symfony Guard and Symfony Authentication provider but despite everything I tried, both variables $last_email and $error are always empty.

I have followed this step by step: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/security/form_login_setup.html and all of my LoginFormAuthenticator.php is identical. So is my controller and login.html.twig

```
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils, Request $request, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker): Response
{
    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    dump($error);

    // last username entered by the user
    $last_email = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
        'last_email' => $last_email,
        'error'      => $error,
    ]);
}
```

Here, even if the email does not exist or the password is invalid, $error is always null. Why?

Here are the logs:

> [2020-08-23 11:53:35] request.INFO: Matched route "login".
> {"route":"login","route_parameters":{"_route":"login","_controller":"App\Controller\SecurityController::login"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/login","method":"POST"}
> [2020-08-23 11:53:35] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard
> authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticators":1}
> [2020-08-23 11:53:35] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard
> authenticator.
> {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator"}
> [2020-08-23 11:53:35] security.DEBUG: Calling getCredentials() on
> guard authenticator.
> {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator"}
> [2020-08-23 11:53:35] security.DEBUG: Passing guard token
> information to the GuardAuthenticationProvider
> {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator"}
> [2020-08-23 11:53:35] security.INFO: Guard authentication failed.
> {"exception":"[object]
> (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException(code:
> 0):  at
> /src/Security/LoginFormAuthenticator.php:68)","authenticator":"App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator"}
> [2020-08-23 11:53:35] security.DEBUG: The
> "App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator" authenticator set the response.
> Any later authenticator will not be called
> {"authenticator":"App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator"}
> [2020-08-23 11:53:35] request.INFO: Matched route "login".
> {"route":"login","route_parameters":{"_route":"login","_controller":"App\Controller\SecurityController::login"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/login","method":"GET"}
> [2020-08-23 11:53:35] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard
> authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticators":1}
> [2020-08-23 11:53:35] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard
> authenticator.
> {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator"}
> [2020-08-23 11:53:35] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator does not
> support the request.
> {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator"}
> [2020-08-23 11:53:35] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage
> with an anonymous Token.

My Security.yaml

```
security:
    access_denied_url: /
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: ~ }
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            http_basic: ~
            provider: our_db_provider
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                use_referer: true
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /
                name:     REMEMBERME
                remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
            logout:
                path:  /logout
                target: /
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
    # activate different ways to authenticate

    # activate different ways to authenticate
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
    # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:    [ROLE_USER, ROLE_INVESTOR, ROLE_STARTUP]
        ROLE_INVESTOR: [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_STARTUP:  [ROLE_USER]
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$,             roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

My LoginFormAuthenticator.php

```
class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;
    private $flash;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, FlashBagInterface $flash)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
        $this->flash = $flash;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];

        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
//            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);
        dump($user);
        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

         return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('logged_in'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. I'm using Symfony 4.4

EDIT:
So the login form WORKS - I can log in and log out. But if my email doesn't exist or if my credentials are invalid, no error message get displayed. Doing a var_dump on $error and $last_email returns NULL and empty string, always. Also, I tried to var dump $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']); from my LoginFormAuthenticator in the checkCredentials method and if my credentials are invalid, i can see it returns false. So that works. But somehow, something seems broken in the background.

Comment: Start by commenting out the redirect line at the top of your code.  I suspect you have a double redirect going on and you never even get to the $error = line.  And replace var_dump with Symfony's [dump](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html).

Comment: You have twice `Matched route "login"` at the same time. That can be a problem but not the solution. You should go deeper `AuthenticationUtils` to debug and get more information about where the problem can be.

Comment: ```$authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();``` returns the last exception thrown in your GuardAuthenticator. So you either not throw any exception or the redirect makes you lose the data

Comment: Thank you. I have removed the redirect for test purposes but still have the same issue. @S.LT what do you mean go deeper in AuthenticationUtils? Do you mean debug the function?

Comment: Yes @MilesM., why `Guard authenticator does not support the request`?

Comment: Can you provide your security.yaml configuration in your question? I think it's a problem with your configuration.

Comment: Hi @S.LT Sure, I've updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: What's weird is that it does indeed check if the credentials are correct but in case it's not, no error message is populated. Same with `$last_email` it doesn't work neither.

Comment: After doing some research I think it comes from my cookies.

Comment: I've proposed an answer. Debugging the Login component is not an easy task. the problem can come from many things. The configuration, the Authentificator Class, or the login form itself. The best way to solve it is take time and debug each login step with the profiler. But first, check the configuration file (that we've done and it seems okay).

Answer (score 0):

From different comments under your question, I think you should take a look at the documentation, on each step to check if you haven't forgotten something. [Guard authentification](https://symfony.com/doc/master/security/guard_authentication.html)

For the missing error message, you can throw a custom Exception: [Guard customize error](https://symfony.com/doc/master/security/guard_authentication.html#guard-customize-error)

I see you have not an `onAuthenticationFailure` inside your `LoginFormAuthenticator`.

> onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
> This is called if authentication fails. Your job is to return the Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response object that should be sent to the client. The $exception will tell you what went wrong during authentication.

You can add one to do an action on authentication failure.